# How to Group the same content into one in View?

Tags: 7, views

I am using [Date](https://www.drupal.org/project/date) Module to display the view summary for a particular year and also count the contents are created in the same year.

I have created the several contents in the year of 2016 , it may contain more than 12 contents.

In each content, I have created the DATE field in the format of (Day / Month)

And, I have called all the contents in the block , while clicking the link content , the content detail should be displayed in the page.

[image: Here , I need to display only one link from a year andwhen clicking the links, it should show all the contents are created in the year(2014)]

Help me to sort out this issue

Comment: *And, I have called all the contents in the block*, If you have already called each content then it should be corresponds to content of original content. And that you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look the Archive view /archive it will give you solution.